# RegExp55 to modify lots of Excel Formulas

Tags: regex, excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following spreadsheet in Excel:

```
+---+----+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
|   | A  |              B              |             C              |
+---+----+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
| 1 |    |                             |                            |
| 2 | 12 | =IF(ISERROR(A2/0),"",A2/0)  | =IF(ISERROR(A2*4),"",A2*4) |
+---+----+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

and I'd want to get the following

```
+---+----+--------+-------+
|   | A  |   B    |   C   |
+---+----+--------+-------+
| 1 |    |        |       |
| 2 | 12 | =A2/0  | =A2*4 |
+---+----+--------+-------+
```

so I wrote this VBA code:

```
Sub DeleteIfError()


    Dim c As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim regex As Object, str As String
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With regex
    .Pattern = "=IF(ISERROR\([A-Za-z0-9]+\)"
    .Global = False 'Only First
    End With

For c = 1 To 3
    For r = 1 To 2
        If Cells(r, c).HasFormula Then

            Set matches = regex.Execute(str)
                For Each Match In matches
                    Cells(r, c) = Match.Value
                Next Match
        End If

    Next r
Next c

End Sub
```

but it gives me a run-time error 5020.
I think that the problem is in the pattern but I really can't understand how to fix it. Anyone could help me please?

Comment: Seems you missed to escape the first opening parenthesis?

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `str`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is right, you seems to be missing the most important part : `str = Cells(r, c).Formula` before executing your regex! And afterthat, it should be : `Cells(r, c).Formula = Match.Value` (as you have `=` in your pattern, you will only have one match, so the loop isn't very useful)

Comment: Well, I think the regex is also doing something wrong: `.Pattern = "=IF\(ISERROR\(([^)]+)\).*"` amd then `Cells(r,c).Formula = regex.Replace(str, "=$1")` (see https://regex101.com/r/fZzhVT/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the following fix:

1) Regex must be `^=IF\(ISERROR\(([^)]+)\).*` and replacement pattern should be set to `=$1` (see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZzhVT/1))
 2) You need to use `.Replace` rather than `.Execute` to replace the formulas
 3) The strings you pass must be the formulas and the updated strings should be assigned to the cell formulas.

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `=IF\(ISERROR\(` - a literal char sequence `=IF(ISERROR(`
- `([^)]+)` - capturing group 1 (referred to with `$1` later) matching 1+ chars other than `)`
- `\)` - a literal `)`
- `.*` - the rest of the line up to its end

Code:

```
Sub DeleteIfError()
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim regex As Object, str As String
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With regex
    .pattern = "^=IF\(ISERROR\(([^)]+)\).*"
    .Global = False 'Only First
    End With

For c = 1 To 3
    For r = 1 To 2
        If Cells(r, c).HasFormula Then
             Cells(r, c).Formula = regex.Replace(Cells(r, c).Formula, "=$1")
        End If

    Next r
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I'be been "breaking" my head arounghte RegEx for this, thanks for the detailed explanation

Comment: Just noticed  I copied/pasted some older `Sub` of mine into the code snippet :) Removed.

Comment: Why using `[a-zA-Z](?==IF\(ISERROR\()` in the **RegEx** doesn't return the first character after `"=IF(ISERROR("` , meaning `"A"` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado: See [the **regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/MBVKSK/2), it matches a letter that is followed with `=IF(ISERROR(`.

Comment: I have (thanks to a previous post of yours), so shouldn't it in thes case return the `"A"`? It's not looking for the `"A"` after the `"=IF(ISERROR("` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado: `A` is not followed with `=IF`, but *preceded* with it. The pattern to be used in `regex.Execute` should be `=IF\(ISERROR\(([A-Za-z])`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/MBVKSK/3).

Comment: thanks for all your help, quite "green" to RexEx, but starting to enjoy this tool. I was thinking to find all the letters between `"=IF(ISERROR("` and `")"`

Comment: Then it will look like this: 1) extract all the substring in between with `=IF\(ISERROR\(([^)]+)\)` pattern using `regex.Execute` and then accessing the first match `Submatches(0)`, 2) split or just loop through the chars in the substring checking if they are alpha chars.

Comment: that was the idea, but couldn't get the `RegEx` syntax